# "Merging" Same sized dataframes into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of Dataframes following this kind of pattern:

```
col1  col2  col3   
1     2     3  
1     2     3  
1     2     3 

col1  col2  col3   
1     2     3  
1     2     3  
1     2     3
```

how do I merge them into

```
col1  col2  col3   
[1,1] [2,2] [3,3] 
[1,1] [2,2] [3,3]
[1,1] [2,2] [3,3]
```

I have no idea how to do this, just feels like there should be an easy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataframe are well aligned, you can use `numpy.dstack`

```
import numpy as np

out = pd.DataFrame(np.dstack([df1, df2]).tolist(),
                   index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print(out)

# Output
     col1    col2    col3
0  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
1  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
2  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
```

**Update**

Using only `pandas`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]) \
        .apply(list).unstack(level=1)
print(out)

# Output
     col1    col2    col3
0  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
1  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
2  [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
```

Comment: How would you accommodate your numpy option for a third dataframe?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.dstack([df1, df2, df3]).tolist(), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13]])
df1.applymap(lambda x: [x]) + df2.applymap(lambda x: [x])
```

→

```
          0         1         2
0  [10, 11]  [20, 12]  [30, 13]
1  [10, 11]  [20, 12]  [30, 13]
2  [10, 11]  [20, 12]  [30, 13]
```

Explanation:
`lambda x: [x]` is a function which converts every argument `x` in a list of length 1 containing exactly that argument.

`.applymap` applies this function to every cell in the data frame.

`+` (the sum operator) is "overloaded" for pandas data frames. In particular, the sum `f1 + f2` of two frames (of equal shape) is defined as a new frame containing in each cell the sum of the corresponding cells of the operands (`f1` and `f2`).

This is trivial if the cells contains numbers. But this also works for other data types: In Python lists can be concatenated via the sum operator: `[1, 2] + [50, 60]` → `[1, 2, 50, 60]`.